# JavaScript executeScript on tabs.onUpdated

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

In my code I need to execute the same script every time I update a google tab.
I wrote this code;

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.get(tab.tabId, (current_tab_info) => {
    if (
      current_tab_info.url.search("https://") == 0 &&
      current_tab_info.url.search(".instagram.com/p/") > 0
    ) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "./foreground.js" });
    } else {
      console.log("You are not in instagram");
    }
  });
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabID, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (
    tab.url.search("https://") == 0 &&
    tab.url.search(".instagram.com/p/") > 0
  ) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "./foreground.js" });
  } else {
    console.log("You are not in instagram");
  }
});
```

But executeScript(script) only works on the first "Activate". It does not work on any "Activate" or "Update" after. I want it to execute the script everytime I "Update" the instagram tab,

Note: Manifest v2, Chrome extension.

Also this is foreground.js;

```
const control = document.getElementById("Tasarruflu Downloader");
console.log("control: " + control);
if (control === null) {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.setAttribute("id", "Tasarruflu Downloader");
  button.innerText = "My Button 1";
  document
    .querySelector("._aamu" && "._ae3_" && "._ae47" && "._ae48")
    .appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Pressed a Button");
  });
}
```

How can i execute script in foreground.js file at onActivated and onUpdated events on my main script?

Answer (score 0):

You could inject your script once when opening a tab or URL by using `manifest.json`. There is no need on injecting it over and over again - if code inside the script is not changing.

But you need to modify your script and `tabs` API handlers code. In both places, you need to use [runtime](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/). Things that interest you are:

- `send` method
- `onMessage` event listener

The steps to do it are simple:

1. send a message via `runtime` API when the tab would be updated, refreshed, etc.
2. catch it in the content script by registering `onMessage` listener
3. in the callback you could run code shown in the content script example

In order to find what message is sent you could use something like this:

```js
const message = {
name: 'your name for message',
// additional data here
}
```

Then in the listener callback, you could check if the message has the name you want.